# Use an additional React component within existing app

Tags: html, reactjs

I am very new to React, but was given a dump of code without much direction. I have an existing `App.js`, with a number of hooks, and returns an HTML layout. How do I add a React component of [`react-countdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown) to my existing code?

I need the countdown timer in a specific `<div>` in my HTML, but can I just pass it in, like in the examples on this page?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Countdown date={Date.now() + 10000} />, //new code?
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why not put the Countdown component inside App component?

Comment: If you don't want putting down Countdown component inside App component, check here - https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: @Kid - How would I do that?

Comment: Go to `App` component and put `Countdown` on its return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can put the `Countdown` component inside App like below

```
const App = () => {
     return (
        <>
           <CountDown />
           {OriginalCode here}
        </>
     )
}
```

Comment: Would this be inside my App.js file,specifically the HTML it returns at the end?